# celery with redis is not working well

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm developing celery tasks to aggregate social contents from facebook and twitter.

Tasks are as following

- facebook_service_handler
- facebook_contents_handler
- image_resize
- save_contents_info

'facebook_service_handler' and 'facebook_contents_handler' tasks use facebook open api with urlopen function.

It is working well when urlopen requests is not many. (under 4~5 times)
but when the urlopen request is over the 4~5, worker is not working anymore.

also,
When the celery is stopped, I break the redis and celeryd, and restart celeryd and redis.
last tasks are executed

any body help me about this problem??

I'm working it on the mac os lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should have two different queues, one for network I/O (using eventlet, with which you can "raise" more processes) and one for the other tasks (using multiprocessing). If you feel that this is complicated, take a look at [CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-task-soft-time-limit). I had similar problems when using urllib.open within celery tasks, as the connection might hang and mess the whole system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I have solved my problem. Actually, It was stupid problem. It caused by low concurrency option. But your answer is helpful to make me more smarter. Thanks! ^^